# Creating different directory for DLLS with Inno

Tags: dll, inno-setup, powerbuilder

im totally new to creating installers using Inno Setup and i have managed to create an installer of my current project.

My problem is, is it possible to create another directory for the necessary dlls that will be used by the system?

for example, my project was built using PowerBuilder and PB apps need PB runtime dll and should be either located at the APP ROOT FOLDER or in C:\Program Files\Sysbase\Shared folder.

can i create a script in inno setup where the runtime dlls will be placed in C:\Program Files\Sysbase\Shared

thanks for the help!

Comment: PowerBuilder (at least quite old version 9) doesn't need libraries in that path. Read the section titled by *When deploying them to the end-user machine, they can be placed in one of three locations* in [`this article`](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101371&seqNum=5).

Answer (score 0):

I use Inno Setup. To install to a folder under the install folder:

Source: "C:\PBSource...\SubFolder*"; DestDir: "{app}\SubFolder";

The constant {pf32} is the 32bit Program Files folder. You could have DestDir as:

{pf32}\Sybase\Shared\PowerBuilder

The one issue I see with this is what if your app user doesn't have the PowerBuilder IDE installed? If the app user always has the PB IDE, this will work ok.

One thing to note: Inno Setup doesn't have a function to update the system path. I have asked them to add one but the developer and the more vocal users on the forum have a philosophical aversion to changing the path so he won't do it.

Comment: so you mean unless the end user has the PB IDE, the path, C:\Program Files\Sysbase\Shared folder will be useless because the EXE wont be able to locate the PB runtime DLL?

Comment: What do you mean by *"update the system path"* ? Do you mean adding a path to the `PATH` environment variable ? That's what you can do... Besides, all what the article I've linked in my comment here (though I don't know if it applies to the OP's PB version) can be done in Inno Setup. user3089162, that's correct. Please take a look at a similar article as I linked, but for your PB version. I believe it will be the same, but still. All 3 ways described there can be easily done with Inno Setup.

Comment: TLama, i have tried everything in the link of the article you posted. it is running now but i receive an transaction not connected. i have edited the registry and link the path variable of my app's exe so that the app will reference to my folder that contains PB runtime dlls. please help me. what should i do? is is a db driver problem? im using ms sql server so my app should use pbsnc125.dll right?